# VBA code for changing output of listbox to another worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, listbox

I have a listbox where a user can select any number of 9 items (can select 1 or multiple). Any checked items result in "TRUE" output, otherwise default to "FALSE." Is there any way I can set the output into a different worksheet? Here is the current code which is set to output starting in cell BA1 and downward:

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Change()
    With ListBox1    
        Dim i As Byte
        For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
            Cells(i + 1, "BA") = .Selected(i)
        Next i    
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply reference the worksheet

```
Worksheets("NameOfYourSheet").Cells(i + 1, "BA") = .Selected(i)
```

Note: this implies the required sheet is in the Active Workbook.  If needed, add the workbook reference too

```
Workbooks("NameOfYourBook").Worksheets("NameOfYourSheet").Cells(i + 1, "BA") = .Selected(i)
```